# How to remove menu labels in word press?

Tags: menus

I'm using WordPress Avada Fusion theme but need to remove the menu labels. like following image[image]

Comment: Pretty good docs here: https://theme-fusion.com/avada-doc/header/menu-settings/

Comment: and here: https://theme-fusion.com/forums/topic/menu-icon-without-text-solution/

Answer (score 3):

You'll find it under Avada Menu Options -> Menu Highlight Label